# How to position a div not the text inside?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I would like to align my div 'Test' to the text Discover. With this code, this is the text inside the div (aka. test) that is aligned, not the div. How can I do ?

EDIT : I've added the CSS so you can see what I mean

Thank you

```css
.button_cta {
  height: 90px;
  display: table;
  color: white;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #18C8D2;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

        <section id ="ca" class="col-md-12">
          <div class="container">
            <header class="row">
              <div class="section_title col-lg-12 col-sm-12 col-sm-12">
                <h1>Ça avance</h1>
                <hr class="divider_blue">
              </div>
            </header>

            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                <p>This is it !</p>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="ca-img">
              <img class="ca--img"src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ca-img.png" width="" height="" alt="" />
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-9 col-lg-8 quote">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-2">
                    <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row ca-next">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                <a href="#">DISCVOER &#8594;</a>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <a href="#">
              <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-12 button_cta">
                <p>Test</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </section>
```

Comment: Your HTML is missing.

Comment: Two things.  1. you have an open ```<a>``` in your HTML, before your 'test' maybe that's part of your problem?  2. When you added the CSS you removed the HTML.

Comment: Sorry, I corrected

Comment: What if you did something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/jmr4j8pk/. Is that what you mean?

Comment: If you need test next to discover, why are you putting 'test' into a new grid row?  could you just have ```<a>Discover</a> <a>Test</a>```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution, nested the div inside another row. Thank you

```
  <div class="col-md-12">
<div class="row">
  <a href="#">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-xl-12 button_cta">
    <p>Test</p>
  </div>
</div>
```